# Print a list of tuples as table

Tags: python, string, list, formatting, tuples

I have a list o tuples:

```
list = [(element1, element2, element3), (elementelel4, element5, elementelement6), (el7, el8, elel9)]
```

I want to print it as a table (so the distance between elements should be the same):

```
HEADER1       HEADER2    HEADER3
element1      element2   element3
elementelel4  element5   elementelement6
el7           el8        elel9
```

I was trying to use some examples which I found, but it was used to print a list of lists, and I have a list of tuples.

Comment: *"it was used to print a list of lists, and I have a list of tuples"* - I wouldn't expect that to make much difference. Where is your modification of these examples, and what exactly is wrong with it?

Answer (score 8):

Using [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)

```
print "HEADER1       HEADER2    HEADER3"
for ele1,ele2,ele3 in l:
    print "{:<14}{:<11}{}".format(ele1,ele2,ele3)

HEADER1       HEADER2    HEADER3
element1      element2   element3
elementelel4  element5   elementelement6
el7           el8        elel9
```

Comment: Also available in python3 https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language

Answer (score 4):

You can use `ljust` for left-aligning the element within a fixed width

```
column_width=20
for row in list:             
    for el in row:         
        print el.ljust(column_width), 
    print
```

**output**

```
element1             element2             element3            
elementelel4         element5             elementelement6     
el7                  el8                  elel9
```

Comment: you could set a fixed column_width, but I guess that's not what OP wants.

Answer (score 1):

Python 3 solution:

```
L = [('element1', 'element2', 'element3'),  
     ('elementelel4', 'element5', 'elementelement6'),  
     ('el7', 'el8', 'elel9')]

max_length_column = []
element_in_tuple = 3

for i in range(elements_in_tuple):
    max_length_column.append(max(len(e[i])+2 for e in L))    

for e in L:
    for i in range(element_in_tuple):
        print(e[i].ljust(max_length_column[i]), end='')
    print()
```

output:

```
element1      element2  element3         

elementelel4  element5  elementelement6  

el7           el8       elel9
```

Comment: Your final print should not have an '\n' in it since that leaves an empty line between your output rows

Comment: Also, your code has a bug in it. The line:

for i in range(len(L)):

should be replaced by:

for i in range(elements_in_tuple):

The reason it works this way is because the length of L happens to be 3, which is also the number of elements in the tuple.

You can also calculate the elements_in_tuple by taking the len() of the first element in L

Answer (score 1):

Assume that, all tuples in the list is of the same length, you can use this:

```
l = [('element1', 'element2', 'element3'), ('elementelel4', 'element5', 'elementelement6'), ('el7', 'el8', 'elel9')]
width = max(len(e) for t in l for e in t[:-1]) + 1 
format=('%%-%ds' % width) * len(l[0])
print '\n'.join(format % tuple(t) for t in l)
```

Output:

```
element1     element2     element3
elementelel4 element5     elementelement6
el7          el8          elel9
```

Comment: you shouldn't use a fixed `width`.

Comment: @laike9m what do you mean by fixed width?

Comment: @laike9m Forgive me, it's too complex and I can't understand.

Answer (score 1):

The solution below could be handy too.
Script:

```
list_el = [('element1', 'element2', 'element3'),
           ('elementelel4', 'element5', 'elementelement'),
           ('el7', 'el8', 'elel9')]

row = "{name1:^20}|{name2:^20}|{name3:^20}".format
for tup in list_el:
    print(row(name1=tup[0], name2=tup[1], name3=tup[2]))
```

Output:

```
  element1      |      element2      |      element3      
elementelel4    |      element5      |   elementelement   
    el7         |        el8         |       elel9
```

in the "row" line you can play with formatting and adjust the columns as you need.

Answer (score 0):

Python3 very simple solution with tabs i.e. `\t` and f-string feature:

```
a = [(0.3, 0, 1.57),(0.3, 0, -1.57),(0.3, 0, 0.78)]
for q,w,e in a:
  print(f"{q}\t{w}\t{e}")
```

Output:

```
0.3     0       1.57    
0.3     0       -1.57   
0.3     0       0.78
```